# how to check if several lists have "maximum" number of shared elements and return that list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In addition to a reference list, I have a list of lists of varying lengths and want to be able to eventually choose a single list among these lists that have the maximum number of "shared elements" with that reference list and return that list. is there any better pythonic way to do this?

My data structure and code attempt is as follows:

reference_list = [(0, 0), (3, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]

```
list_1 = [(7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10)]
list_2 = [(6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]
list_3 = [(0, 0), (7, 7), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]
list_4 = [(2, 2), (8, 8), (9, 9), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
#list_5 = [(5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]
#list_6 = [(0, 0), (3, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]

list_of_lists = (list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)#, list_5)#, list_6)


counts = []
#flag = 0
for list_element in list_of_lists:
    count = 0
    print(list_element)
    lengh_of_element = len(list_element)
    for i in range(lengh_of_element):
        if list_element[i] in reference_list:
            count=count+1
    counts.append(count)

maximum_count = max(counts)
max_count_index = counts.index(maximum_count)
selected_list = list_of_lists[max_count_index]
print('the list with maximum number of shared elements with the reference list is: list_', max_count_index+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
s = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists).isin(reference_list).sum(1)
Out[351]: 
0    4
1    7
2    5
3    5
dtype: int64

list_of_lists[s.idxmax()]

Out[352]: [(6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (15, 19), (15, 20)]
```